# Avoiding a Frozen valve stem

Tags: tires

Ive had to add air to my tires in sub zero temps and have had the valve stems freeze open, Or have had the compressor valve freeze. How do I avoid this.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Check tire pressures before cold weather.

Comment: I’m curious. How do you know those valves are “freezing open”. In my experience when one of those valves starts leaking it’s because the polymer seal in the valve spins out of its seat. 

When you remove a “frozen” valve and inspect with a magnifying glass, what do you see?

Answer (score 1):

The stems are freezing simply because it's cold and the moisture in the air is turning to ice. The only ways to prevent this problem would be:

1: Use nitrogen instead of air to inflate your tires. Nitrogen does not hold or collect water so there is nothing to freeze. Availability is a deterant but some shops have it available.

2: Of course the other only option I can think of is to air up in a heated environment.

Comment: This isn't quite true. [Neither pure nitrogen or air absorbs water](https://hvacrschool.com/does-air-or-nitrogen-absorb-water/). Water vapor is a gas much like nitrogen or oxygen and will be in suspension in air or in nitrogen, unless the air/nitrogen is purified or dried out. Pure nitrogen won't have water or water vapor because it's all nitrogen. You could clean air up so it doesn't have any water vapor in it just the same.

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely that the air in the tires contain sufficient water vapor to cause the valve stem to freeze. If the ambient temperatures are that low, the water vapor has already condensed and settled in the tire.

It's more likely that the air source is providing the moisture. Going from a compressed (and implied cooled) state in the compressor tank to an expanded form to the tire will cool the air, creating condensed water at the valve stem.

Ensure that your source is dry air by using a separator filter on the output of the compressor. If the tank is in a warm area, moving it to a cooler area, if possible, will condense out the moisture, which should then be drained before the air is dispensed.

My high capacity compressor is bolted to the garage floor, but after each compression cycle, it activates the automatic drain system, forcing any condensed water from the system. The unit also has a DIY Franzinator which prevents the moisture from entering the tank.

In smaller compressor systems, the output filter may be the only option to prevent moisture at the valve stem.